# How to adjust the brightness of a small LCD(21V) with a potentiometer?

Tags: timer, lcd, dimming

I want to adjust the brightness of a small LCD with a potentiometer. How can I use a 555 timer to make a PWM which can give out an output of 21V from a 5V input?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Do you want to generate 21V from 5V, or do you want to PWM an existing large voltage with a 555?

Comment: Sorry. I want to boost 5V to 21V, and control the 21V with PMW. I don't know how to do it because the 555 IC limit is 18V.

Comment: Brightness is determined by a backlight.   What kind of backlight does the display have?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a source of 22 volts. You could use a boost converter if all you have is 5V.

You need a high-side switch, this is not as easy as a low-side switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsHNSn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transistors are not critical, any small switching signal transistor should work.

The resistor values may need to be adjusted depending on how much current that the PWM input requires.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. Take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPYx4qT_EeU for an example.

Comment: A link - especially a Youtube link - is not an answer.